# App crashing on Subscription on live mode in Swift5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, subscription

I was working on apple subscription and have set two subscription plan on apple store for "monthly" and "yearly" and have set up all the code which is working perfectly on development and adhoc. But after placing build on App Store app crashes.
I have used firebase crashlytic which detected crash I have attached screenshot crash logs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e487d.png

Here my code for Subscription:

```
  func getProducts(productIDs: [String]){
    //self.showLoader()
    print("Start requesting products ...")
    //showAlert(text:"Start requesting products ...")
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(productIDs))
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
}

func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    if response.products.isEmpty {
        NotificationAlert().NotificationAlert(titles: "No subscription plan")
    }else{
        self.myProducts = response.products
        for invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
            print(invalidIdentifier)
            //NotificationAlert().NotificationAlert(titles:"Invalid Identifire")
        }
        print("Did receive response")
        for fetchedProduct in response.products{
            //DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("fetchedProduct:",fetchedProduct)
            //showAlert(text:"Product Fetched")
            //NotificationAmyProductslert().NotificationAlert(titles: "fetchedProduct:\(fetchedProduct)")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1.0, execute: {
                let price = self.getPrice(item: fetchedProduct)
                if price == ""{
                    
                } else{
                    self.myProducts.append(fetchedProduct)
                    if fetchedProduct.productIdentifier == "com.motivatory.monthly"{
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.3, execute: {
                            self.oPriceMonthlyLbl.text = price ?? ""
                            self.monthlyprice = price ?? ""
                            print(price ?? "")
                            self.productIDs.insert("com.motivatory.monthly",at: 0)
                            self.selectedPrice = price ?? ""
                        })
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.3, execute: {
                            self.oPriceYearlyLbl.text = price ?? ""
                            self.selectedPrice = price ?? ""
                            self.yearlyPrice = price ?? ""
                            print(price ?? "")
                            self.productIDs.insert("com.motivatory.yearly",at: 1)
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

func getPrice(item: SKProduct) -> String? {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    let price = item.price
    let locale = item.priceLocale
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    numberFormatter.locale = locale
    return numberFormatter.string(from: price)
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        print(transaction)
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                purchaseTokenStr = trans.transactionIdentifier ?? ""
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                if self.purchased == true {
                    print("Product Purchased")
                    print(purchaseTokenStr)
                    receiptValidation()
                }
                break;
            case .failed:
                purchaseTokenStr = trans.transactionIdentifier ?? ""
                NotificationAlert().NotificationAlert(titles: "Payment failed")
                print("Purchased Failed");
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                break;
            case .restored:
                print("Already Purchased")
                purchaseTokenStr = trans.transactionIdentifier ?? ""
                // receiptValidation()
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
//added by me
// 4:
func finishTransaction(_ transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) -> Bool {
    let productId = transaction.payment.productIdentifier
    //print("Product \(productId) successfully purchased”)
    print("Product \(productId) successfully purchased")
    return true
}

func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
//If an error occurs, the code will\ go to this function
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    NotificationAlert().NotificationAlert(titles: error.localizedDescription)
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    if queue.transactions.count == 0{
        NotificationAlert().NotificationAlert(titles: "Please purchase a subscription plan")
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    } else{
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            if self.purchaseTokenStr == t.transactionIdentifier {
                switch prodID {
                case "com.motivatory.yearly":
                    print("Your Yearly Plan has Restored Successfully")
                    NotificationAlert().NotificationAlert(titles: "Your Yearly Plan has Restored Successfully")
                    receiptValidation()
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    break
                case "com.motivatory.monthly":
                    print("Your Montly Plan has Restored Successfully")
                    NotificationAlert().NotificationAlert(titles: "Your Montly Plan has Restored Successfully")
                    receiptValidation()
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    break
                default:
                    if queue.transactions.count == 0 {
                        self.alert(message: "There are no restorable purchases. Only previously bought non-consumable products and auto-renewable subscriptions can be restored.", title: "Inspiration Daily Quotes")
                        break
                    }
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func receiptValidation(){
    self.HitReceiptApi(Url: "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")
}

func HitReceiptApi(Url:String){
    SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.custom)
    SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundLayerColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2472442209))
    SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Please Wait")
    let receiptFileURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL
    let receiptData = try? Data(contentsOf: receiptFileURL!)
    let recieptString = receiptData?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    
    let jsonDict: [String: AnyObject] = ["receipt-data" : recieptString! as AnyObject, "password" : "fad24ce1475b4fdd9662a0ec31ef5a7d" as AnyObject]
    print(jsonDict)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(recieptString!, forKey: "recieptString")
    do {
        let requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        let storeURL = URL(string: Url)!
        var storeRequest = URLRequest(url: storeURL)
        storeRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        storeRequest.httpBody = requestData
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: storeRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                print("=======>",jsonResponse)
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    if json["status"] as? Int == 21007{
                        print("Sandbox User")
                        self?.HitReceiptApi(Url: "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt")
                        return
                    } else {
                        print("Production")
                        if self!.purchaseTokenStr == ""{
                            
                        } else {
                            self?.purchaseTokenStr = ""
                            if let receiptInfo2: NSArray = json["pending_renewal_info"] as? NSArray {
                                let lastReceipt2 = receiptInfo2.lastObject as! NSDictionary
                                if let original_transaction_id = lastReceipt2["original_transaction_id"] as? String {
                                    self?.purchaseTokenStr = original_transaction_id
                                }
                            }
                            if let receiptInfo2: NSArray = json["latest_receipt_info"] as? NSArray {
                                let lastReceipt2 = receiptInfo2.firstObject as! NSDictionary
                                if let purchase_date = lastReceipt2["purchase_date"] as? String {
                       if let date = Formatter.customDate.date(from:purchase_date){
                                        var startDate1 = String(describing: date)
                                        startDate1.removeLast(6)
                                        self?.startDate = "\(startDate1)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            self?.buySubscription = true
                            self?.subscriptionBuy()
                        }
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    }
                   UserDefaults.standard.set(true,forKey:"SubscriptionPurchased")
                }
            } catch let parseError {
                print(parseError)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    } catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: NotificationAlert().NotificationAlert(titles: "No subscription plan") this line should be  in main thread ?

Comment: Is crashing in second `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter + 0.3` closure

Comment: I would say is this line `self.productIDs.insert("com.motivatory.yearly",at: 1)`, you are sure that your productIDs have position 0 occuped?

Comment: btw `self.monthlyprice`is only updated in first closure, second closure should not update it??

Comment: 100 percent crash on DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter, what is the significance of asyncAfter here

Comment: how can I test without upload current version?. I am getting crash only on production mode is there any way I can test it before uploading?

Comment: @Vikassaini not helped I removed DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter from code still crashing.